# Imagemagick crop doesn't seem to be respecting gravity center

Tags: imagemagick, png, center, crop, gravity

bulk cropping PNG images which were previously rotated with Imagemagick using

`convert thistle-7gn.png  -rotate 75 thistle-7gn-75.png`

this command

`magick thistle-7gn-75.png -gravity center -crop 1600x1600+0+0 +repage thistle-7gn-75-cropped.png;`

[EDIT: images appear to be converted from PNG to JPG when I upload]
[EDIT 2: Imgur converts large PNG to JPG intentionally—links to original PNG]
`https://spinhead.com/thistle-7gn-75.png`
`https://spinhead.com/thistle-7gn-75-cropped.png`

with the attached image results in the off-center crop, also attached.

my understanding of the command is to use 'magick' rather than 'convert', then filename, set the origin to center rather than top left using '-gravity center', crop to size X by Y plus offset of X-direction Y-direction FROM THE CENTER OF THE ORIGINAL IMAGE, output new filename

I have successfully done exactly this process multiple times in the past months and thought I had crop with gravity sussed, but despite using what appears to be the same syntax with different images, it's not behaving as I expect.

*Mac Mini Monterey, ImageMagick 7.1.1-15 Q16-HDRI x86_64 21298*

Comment: The input from the camera has flag for the orientation.  Did you rotate manually or with -auto-rotate.  Also after a crop, you need to use +repage to remove the virtual canvas.

Comment: You posted an input JPG not PNG. So your command using the jpg input works fine for me.  If you have the PNG input version, put +repage after the crop.

Comment: "The input from the camera has flag for the orientation"

I don't know what that means or how it applies to the offset when cropping. 

I edited to correct my command, which did include +repage.

Posted PNGs and don't know why they're JPG now. Testing with JPG it does indeed work as expected. However, I have to retain transparency for flattening into a composite later in the process.

Comment: If you start with the PNG and add +repage after the crop, it should work.  Give that a try.  The orientation flag will allow IM -auto-orient to automatically rotate the image. If the image is rectangular rather than square, then the center off can be off if the image is not properly rotated first; otherwise rows might become columns and vice versa.

Comment: I started with a PNG and used repage and everything is square, and it doesn't work. You did see that the images I posted are square, yes? and the command I'm using refers to PNG files? and I edited my post AND included a comment that I AM using +repage?

So, no, doing those things does not making it work, because that's already what I'm doing.

Comment: Can you post your input PNG rather than JPG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input PNG, which I was able to download from thistle-7gn-75.png  has a virtual canvas offset, which I can see from `identify -verbose thistle-7gn-75.png` as *Page geometry: 4374x4374-587-587*.

That means you need to remove the virtual canvas offset using +repage right after reading the input PNG.

So the following now works fine in Imagemagick for me.

Input:

[image]

```
magick thistle-7gn-75.png +repage -gravity center -crop 1600x1600+0+0 +repage thistle-7gn-75-cropped.png
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Brilliant. I know far less about inspecting images than mogrifying. The offset in my broken crop is exactly that offset amount, so this is the solution. Had no idea to repage BEFORE the process.

Thank you so much for sticking with me through this. I very much appreciate your patience and help.

Comment: PNG supports a virtual canvas.  When you crop and do not add +repage after the crop it leaves the virtual canvas around.  So it is a good idea when reading PNG to add +repage after the read to remove any potential virtual canvas before doing any subsequent processing such as -crop and -trim.